# Extracting Model and VIN from URL (second time pattern appears, but with date in addition to make)

Tags: python, pandas, regex, dataframe, jupyter

Tried:

```py
# model_pattern = r'\d{4}\-([^/]+)\-'
model_pattern = r'[-]([^/]+)\-'
```

WANT MODEL:
`2021-Mercedes-Benz-Sprinter+2500`
AND VIN: 
`286f67180a0e09a8729929613aac3877`
FROM:
`/used/Mercedes-Benz/2021-Mercedes-Benz-Sprinter+2500-286f67180a0e09a8729929613aac3877.htm`

Another one, this one has no "+" in it:
`/used/Audi/2015-Audi-SQ5-286f67180a0e09a8729929613aac3877.htm`

I use

```
Clean_Make["Model"] = Clean_Make["Page"].str.extract(model_pattern)
Clean_Make
```

This is the resulting table:

```
    Page    City    Pageviews   Unique Pageviews    Avg. Time on Page   Entrances   Bounce Rate % Exit  Make1   Make2   Make    Model
71  /used/Mercedes-Benz/2021-Mercedes-Benz-Sprinte...   San Jose    310 149 00:00:27    149 2.00%   47.74%  Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz-Sprinter+2500
103 /used/Audi/2015-Audi-SQ5-286f67180a0e09a872992...   Menlo Park  250 87  00:02:36    82  0.00%   32.40%  Audi    Audi    Audi    Audi-SQ5
158 /used/Mercedes-Benz/2021-Mercedes-Benz-Sprinte...   San Francisco   202 98  00:00:18    98  2.04%   48.02%  Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz-Sprinter+2500
165 /used/Audi/2020-Audi-S8-c6df09610a0e09af26b5cf...   San Francisco   194 93  00:00:42    44  2.22%   29.38%  Audi    Audi    Audi    Audi-S8
168 /used/Mercedes-Benz/2021-Mercedes-Benz-Sprinte...   (not set)   192 91  00:00:11    91  2.20%   47.40%  Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz   Mercedes-Benz-Sprinter+2500
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
4995    /used/Subaru/2019-Subaru-Crosstrek-5717b3040a0...   Union City  10  3   00:02:02    0   0.00%   30.00%  Subaru  Subaru  Subaru  Subaru-Crosstrek
4996    /used/Tesla/2017-Tesla-Model+S-15605a190a0e087...   San Jose    10  5   00:01:29    5   0.00%   50.00%  Tesla   Tesla   Tesla   Tesla-Model+S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
/([^/]+)-([a-f0-9]{32})\.htm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yWiUd3/2).

*Details*:

- `/` - a `/` char
- `([^/]+)` - Group 1  (model): one or more chars other than `/`
- `-` - a hyphen
- `([a-f0-9]{32})` - Group 2 (VIN): 32 hex chars
- `\.htm` - a `.htm` string.

In Pandas, you can use

```py
Clean_Make[["Model", "VIN"]] = Clean_Make["Page"].str.extract(r'/([^/]+)-([a-f0-9]{32})\.htm', expand=False)
```